# RecordNotFound with Capybara-webkit AJAX request

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, selenium, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

I have a form to create a new `Address`. The form includes the id of the parent model (in this case a `Customer`) that owns the `Address`. When submitting the form the AJAX request goes to the `AddressesController` which responds with JavaScript. The problem is that sometimes, the parent model is found and sometimes not.

This works in RSpec:

```
before do
    click_link add_address
    fill_in country_field, with: country
    fill_in city_field, with: city
    fill_in street_field, with: street
    fill_in postal_code_field, with: postal_code
    click_button submit_address
    expect(page.title).to eq(show_page_title)
end

it { is_expected.to have_content(address_created) }
```

But when I move the `expect(page.title).to eq(show_page_title)` from the before-statement to an own test (which of course is better):

```
it { is_expected.to have_title(show_page_title) }
it { is_expected.to have_content(address_created) }
```

I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
  Couldn't find Customer with 'id'=1
```

If I add `puts Customer.count` last in the before-statement as well as in the `AddressesController` where the request is received, I get 1 from the line in the before-statement but 0 from the controller! How is this possible?

Comment: It seams like [Automatically wait for AJAX with Capybara](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/automatically-wait-for-ajax-with-capybara) solved it, though I need to do some more testing before I'm sure.

Comment: I can now confirm that the solution above solved my problem. I'm not sure why because the ``Customer`` should be created before the tests are run since I create it with a ``let!(:customer) { FactoryGirl.create(:customer) }`` statement.